# Unique solution for second order BVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

How do I show that this BVP has a unique solution? I know how to do it for first order but not for second order.

$$y''=-xy'+4y-8x+5, \quad \text{ where } y(0)=1, y(1)=0$$

I know that you have to show it is continuous, but I only know how to do it for first order BVP. I don't mind if you don't answer this exact equation, I just wanna know how to do it with an example. Thanks

Comment: Write your ODE as a system of ODEs?

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean I should write them as two first order equations?

Comment: Yes, write them as two first order ODEs by setting $y' = z$. Then use the information [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372437/existence-and-uniqueness-of-system-of-odes) and [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-iv-first-order-systems/matrix-exponentials/MIT18_03SCF11_s35_2text.pdf).

Comment: I got $u'_1 = u_2$ and $u'_2 = -xu_2+4u_1-8x+5$ by settings $u_1 = y$ and $u_2 = y'$. So I just do the same as with a first order?

Comment: Just set $y' = z \implies z' = y'' = -xz + 4y - 8x + 5$.

Comment: Yep sorry, you're right. So do I do the same as first order?

Comment: Almost. Just follow the working [here](https://calculus7.org/2012/06/13/uniqueness-for-an-ode-system/), though note that you have an inhomogeneity which makes your problem more difficult.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot

Comment: Finally, [this might also help](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~kazdan/202F13/notes/ODE1.pdf).